# Linking compiler commands directly rather than adding the correct path to environmental variables

Tags: fortran, openmpi, intel-mpi

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780992/mpirun-unrecognized-argument-mca) post, I had a problem with the version of `mpirun` I was using. A fast solution (even if it did not solve all the issues) was to add the path to the `openmpi` version of `mpirun` in my `PATH` environmental variable so my shell knew to look there first when looking for this command.

In another code I am using, I need to call the intel version of `mpif77`. One quick solution would be again to add the correct path to my environmental variable. However, this means that I can have only one code working automatically, while for the other code I would need to do some pre-processing to make sure I am linking the correct version of the `mpi` command.

Is there a way to bypass that? For example, I would like to link only `mpif77` to its intel version and `mpic++` only to the openmp version rather than doing it through the `PATH` environmental variable, which in the end is convenient if you work only with either openmp or intel, but not both.

Comment: Look into modules. They are normally used on supercomputers, but also other Unix computers, for this purpose. Alternatively, you can prepare a short script that switches between the MPI libraries and sets the correct `PATH` variables.

Comment: Intel MPI names its Intel-specific compiler wrappers differently: `mpiicc` (notice the extra `i`), `mpiifort`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an alias in your shell configuration?

```
alias intel_mpif77="/path/to/wrappercompiler"
alias ompi_mpic++= ...
```